# HTML view not getting displayed on Mobile device when using JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using JQuery Mobile for mobile application development. I have designed my view. Its running fine on browser when tested but on mobile device its showing black screen. Please share any experience.

My Login Screen:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>     
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
    <title>MyApp</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquerymobile120.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default320.css" />     
    </head>
    <body id="content" style="display: none">
<div data-role="page" id="login" class="MainCon">
<div class="MastHead" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
<div class="MastHeadInner">
<div class="HeaderLogo"><img alt="" title="" src="images/logo.png"  /></div>

</div>
</div>

    <div data-role="content">

            <div id="AuthDiv" class ="LoginBox" style="display:none">
                <div  class="LogBoxCon">
                    <p>
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="iconin" placeholder="user ID" id="AuthUsername"/>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <input type="password" name="password"  class="iconid" placeholder="password" id="AuthPassword"/>
                    </p>
                    <div class="BtnLog">
                        <a class ="LightGrayBtn LoginBtn" href="#" id="AuthSubmitButton">login</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please share more details.

Comment: How is this related to worklight?

Comment: Which device are you testing on? Which Worklight version? Which jQuery Mobile version? Share entire HTML file.

Comment: @Omar,Orlando,Idan : I am using Eclipse IDE with worklight as plugin added to it. Worklight provision us to use JQuery Mobile for mobile application development.

Eclipse Version:  Juno Service Release 2
Worklight version : 6.0

Answer (score 1):

Where is all the Worklight-related portion in the HTML file you've pasted in the question?
This HTML code... is this in the MAIN HTML file of the application, or one of yours? If it is an additional HTML file, how do you load it?

A basic HTML file looks like the following. Note all the missing references in yours compared to the below.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>testapp</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/testapp.css">
            <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
        </head>
        <body id="content" style="display: none;">
            <!--application UI goes here-->
            testapp
            <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
            <script src="js/testapp.js"></script>
            <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```